# Difference between let import React from 'react/addons' and import { PropTypes } from 'react/addons'

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between the two:

```
import React from 'react/addons';
let {PropTypes} = React;
```

vs

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react/addons';
```

Is there any proper convention that we should follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often, compiling these to ES5 with [Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl) is a great way to understand what's going on.

```
import React from 'react/addons';
let {PropTypes} = React;
```

Becomes:

```
var _addons = require('react/addons');

var _addons2 = _interopRequireDefault(_addons);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var PropTypes = _addons2.default.PropTypes;
```

Compared to:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react/addons';
```

Which becomes:

```
var _addons = require('react/addons');

var _addons2 = _interopRequireDefault(_addons);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

The first two statements in each are identical. The import statements become calls to `require`, then there's a runtime helper function which extracts the appropriate value from inside the module.

At this point it becomes interesting. Example 1 makes use of object destructuring to introduce `PropTypes` as a new variable. Babel introduces the new variables as references pointing towards the appropriate properties.

```
var PropTypes = _addons2.default.PropTypes;
```

So why is this line of code missing from example 2? In fact, if you check out the code, you'll notice that even though it looks like we should have a `PropTypes` variable in scope, there isn't one. Bit of a mystery?

## Further Experiments

Again, Babel's REPL can help us out here. Let's see what happens if we write some code that uses `PropTypes` and compile that.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react/addons';

console.log(PropTypes);
```

Which becomes:

```
var _addons = require('react/addons');

var _addons2 = _interopRequireDefault(_addons);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

console.log(_addons.PropTypes);
```

A few important things to notice.

- It compiles references to `PropTypes` into `_addons.PropTypes`
- It's using `_addons` not `_addons2` (unlike example 1)

This happens because the `{ PropType } from` syntax in example 2 is **not destructuring**.

## Named Imports

If we follow this up in the [ES2015 specification [15.2.2]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports), we'll see this syntax described as *NamedImports*.

```
NamedImports :
  { }
  { ImportsList }
  { ImportsList , }
```

This syntax is designed for extracting *named exports* from an imported module.

For instance, if the react/addons package was published as an ES6 module, it would have to look like this for the second syntax to work.

```
export const PropTypes = {
  // prop types
};

export default React;
```

Which compiles to:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
var PropTypes = exports.PropTypes = {};

// prop types
exports.default = React;
```

`PropTypes` is added as a *named export* to the `exports` object.

## Conclusion

```
import React from 'react/addons';
let {PropTypes} = React;
```

This is general destructuring syntax. It works when the `exports.default` value has a `PropTypes` field.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react/addons';
```

This syntax is for accessing named exports. It works when the react/addons module exports a named value for `PropTypes` and a default value for `React`.

Comment: So is there any preference as to use which one?

Comment: It depends what the module exports?